# Return a string with conditions

Tags: javascript

Here is a code to return the string if user input is a trap (I sent , they is). The explanation is another problem for me so let's have a look at the code instead:

```js
let trapSt = 'I was sent = I sent. they are = they is'; // correct version = trap version

// prepare the trapSt and make an array
trapSt = trapSt.toLowerCase().replace(/\s+/g, " ").split(".").map(s => s.trim());
trapSt = trapSt.filter(s => s);

console.log(trapSt);

// return the whole part of string if user inputs the trap
function findTrap(str) {
  let trapPairs = trapSt.map(s => s.split(' = '));
  console.log(trapPairs)
  let matchI = trapPairs.findIndex(([first]) => first === str);
  return trapSt[matchI] || false;
};

let findTrapResult = findTrap('i was sent'); // should return false
//let findTrapResult = findTrap('i sent'); // should return "i was sent = i sent" because it's a trap
console.log(findTrapResult);
```

The problem is the code does exactly the opposite of what I want and I need a hand to fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are comparing the wrong values in `trapPairs`. You are destructuring the argument in such a way that you only have the first element (the left hand side). If you want to match on the right hand side of the equals, you need the second element in the array. You can do that with something like this:

```js
function findTrap(str) {
  let trapPairs = trapSt.map(s => s.split(' = '));
  console.log(trapPairs)
  let matchI = trapPairs.findIndex(([first, second]) => second === str);
  return trapSt[matchI] || false;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

rfestag's answer would work.

I'd propose another possible solution: think of the trap version as a key so that you can map to the result. We can create an object out of the trap string and look up the result, if there's no match, return `false`

```js
const trapSt = 'I was sent = I sent. they are = they is'

const traps = Object.fromEntries(
  trapSt
    .toLowerCase()
    .split('.')
    .map((fullStr) => {
      const trap = fullStr.split('=')[1].trim()

      return [trap, fullStr.trim()]
    }),
)

const findTrap = (str) => traps[str] || false

console.log(findTrap('i was sent'))
console.log(findTrap('i sent'))
```